# Git stopped working after adding and removing a submodule

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Ok,
I read lots of answers in stackoverflow and the net, none of them helped me.

The problem started with git version Git-1.7.10-preview20120409 and tortoiseGit TortoiseGit-1.7.10.0-64bit later on I upgraded to Git-1.8.0-preview20121022 and tortoiseGit 1.7.15, I was hoping it will solve my problem

I'm working with git for few months now almost only through the tortoiseGit. Most of the work I done till now is having few repositories hosted on Assembla and each one have few branches and I'm doing mostly common stuff.

Today I tried to add an open source sub-module to the project, it went fine but then I decided to go with the sub-tree approach. Till that point i didn't commit anything to the locals branches and I didn't push anything to my remote server. Since I didn't see any easy was to remove the sub-module, I tried to revert my branch to the last known commit, it didn't really work, so I deleted the .gitmodules file and the relevant section from the config file and the sub-module folder. Since stuff still weren't working exactly, I decided to delete the whole repository from my local machine and to clone it again. I thought that since I didn't commit anything nor pushed I would be OK. But after the clone finish with success and I press on the OK button I get the following message *Fail set config remote.origin.puttykeyfile* After pressing OK almost nothing is working, so I tried to change the settings like this: in the reop folder right click->TortoiseGit->Settings->git->Remote and I'm getting the following error fatal: *Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/thirdPartyName*. Of course the specified folder is not even exist, I tried to create it manually and running the *git init* command on that folder, still didn't help me.

Nothing I read helped me to solve my problem, so I upgraded GIT and I removed tortoiseGit and installed a new version. I still have the same problems, I think that the problem is related to the fact that tortoiseGit doesn't clean the settings when you uninstall it.

With the new versions of git and tortoiseGit I get almost the same errors.
*Could not initialize libgit. libgit reports: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/thirdParty*

Now my situation is that all my repositories on my computer doesn't work. I'm almost sure that it is something with the setting of git or tortoiseGit since it doesn't work with other unrelated repositories also.

I would really appreciate help,

Thanks

--EDIT--
It looks like GIT is working fine from the command line, so I assume that the problem is with tortoiseGit

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to reduce the problem to one thing at a time. TortoiseGit sits on top of Git for Windows. So start using only Git for Windows (command line only) until you get that working you can't really expect to get TortoiseGit working.

If you deleted the local repository and re-cloned then nothing remained on your machine except the global git config and system git config files. Therefore your problem must lie in one of those files. It is unlikely that the system git config was modified so it is probably the global (your per-user) git config. This is in $HOME/.gitconfig (or %USERPROFILE%.gitconfig using the cmd shell). Open that file with something that can show the line endings and check that it all looks ok. It probably should be unix line endings but it definately should not have mixed dos and unix line endings -- I have seen some tools add dos line endings to a file that had unix line endings making a mess.

If it looks ok and things remain broken, try deleting the file and then to `git config --global -l` to see what remains. This should only be stuff in the system config file which is in %PROGRAMFILES%\Git\etc\gitconfig (or /etc/gitconfig in the msys shell). Check that over.

If it still looks ok and is still all broken, check the virtual store. If you normally run with a non-administrative account and something tried to edit the system config then Windows has an irritating scheme where it makes a virtual copy. These are in %LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore. If that contains a "Program Files\Git" folder then you are suffering from this mis-feature and should delete the files under there.

Finally, you could try the PortableGit -- I think that makes every config file be used from some alternate location which should insulate you from a bad local config file.

Comment: First, thanks for the detailed answer. I edited my question while you answered. It looks like GIT is working through the command line, which means that the problems probably related to the tortoiseGit. I followed your instructions even that the GIT is working, just to see it it does the trick. 1. The line have the Unix line ending 2. I didn't delete the config file, since it looks fine and GIT is working so I believe that this is not the problem, if you still think it is worth deleting I would try it 3. I deleted the VirtualStore\gitFolder. 4. Again, the problem is probably with tortoiseGit

Comment: Do you know how to fix the tortoiseGit problem? Thanks

Comment: I don't use TortoiseGit so I can't offer any help on that. Our developers that use GUI interfaces to git tend to use GitExtensions on Windows instead - possibly that is worth a try. It may be worth asking on a more specific TortoiseGit mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I uninstalled tortoiseGit again but this time I did it through the installation file and not through the add/remove programs and from some reason it did the trick. I have no idea what happened here, and since I did lots of operations it is really hard to reconstruct this bug. Thanks for everything. I don't mark your answer as the one that solved my problem, since it didn't, but I up vote your answer since I think that it written well and there are few steps that worth trying for this kind of situations.